# Minimum number of ports needed for HTTP

Tags: attacks, ddos, router

I am supporting a public campground that provides web site access to its customers via a Time Warner Cable connection with wireless AP points in the park. 
The allowed port usage is blocking some obviously not needed ports like FTP, and other non-essential ports.

My question is, should I revert to only allowing the minimum number of port access to these customers to support HTTP only with perhaps DNS.  If that is a good strategy, then what would be the minimum ports allowed for Web page access.

Comment: I'm curious about why you want to limit what services your customers can access? What security benefit do you hope to gain? What threat do you wish counter?

Comment: The park has been under serious ddos attacks from outside as well and occasionally inside the wifi system.  It is a public access wifi and we have no control over the customers computers if they have viruses on them.  I feel that the attacks can be severely limited by only allowing ports to support web browsing. Therefore blocking attempts to scan the system for open ports.

Comment: I'd leave the SSH open as well.

Answer (score 1):

Well,if you **only** want HTTP access, it would be enough to open port 80 tcp (HTTP) to the outside.

You can also open port 53 (udp & tcp) so they can use a public dns server, or provide a dns resolver yourself for your customers (*not open to the internet*). You might decide to ditch dns and expect them to input IP addresses directly, but that's unlikely to be enjoyed by your users.

However, that way you are not suporting **HTTPS**, which means they won't be able to access many websites, from their bank (*I need to log in there in order to authorise this purchase on your shop…*) to twitter (*I just wanted me to tweet how fun your park was…*) or Wikipedia. So also port 443 tcp would be a minimum.

However, there are websites for which you would need [port 8000](http://westonwatson.com:8000/), [port 8080](http://nbzxl.com:8080/), [port 8888](http://oakbridge.servebeer.com:8888/)…

Plus, although you claim that you only want to provide website access, I'm pretty sure your customers expect to connect their smartphones and be able to use their apps, which -although predominantly they will be HTTP(S)-based- may use any port.

Would that help you with your DDOS attacks? That seems unlikely. You don't specify the details in which you were attacked, but even for the small cases in which it was launched from the inside, they could do it with only port 80 open. It is more important to properly limit the resources by your different clients to ensure a fair use of them. Up to blocking of abusive devices if needed.

Comment: Thanks Angel,   As I expected, there isn't much hope for trying to limit exposure from ddos.  It is true that we were hit from numerous ports including 80, 53, etc.  So that strategy does seem questionable.  So thanks for your input.